# C++ very simple unresolved external

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

I have an unresolved external in Visual Studio C++ compiler that's driving me absolutely crackers. The class header and source files are extremely simple.

Header file:

```
// Header file: Rational.h
class Rational
{
public:
    Rational ( int = 0, int = 1 ); 
private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;    
};
```

Source file:

```
// Source file: Rational.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Rational.h"

using namespace std;

Rational::Rational( int n, int d )
{
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
}
```

The error messages are:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function    ___tmainCRTStartup    

error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

How is this possible? I must be missing something very fundamental here but now I am at the end of my tether.

I have looked at other questions on this topic but can't find an answer.

Comment: Have you got a `main()`?

Comment: You forgot to define the entry point...  create a new file and add `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: @OliKlima Well that is pretty important

Comment: Apologies all I didn't realise I needed main. This is fixed now. Thanks, and apologies for the silly question.

Answer (score 4):

> Have you got a `main()`? – Alan Stokes
>   @ Alan. Not yet. – OliKlima

Well, there you go then.

It's the `main` that's not being found, as the error message pretty much states.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to link `Rational.cpp` into an executable, it needs an entry point (`main`). If you're simply creating an object file, then there is no linking done. Your entry point can be placed in another file, i.e `main.cpp`, and then link it together.

First, put this in `main.cpp`:

```
int main()
{
}
```

Then run the following commands:

```
g++ -c Rational.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o rational.o
```

Comment: Thanks, I won't be making that mistake again :)